# Using Telerek Just Decompile to re-create a .NET source projectL: Unable to debug as normal

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, decompiling

We lost some source code, so I used Telerek's Just Decompile to decompile a dll and create a C# project in Visual Studio. I changed project that referenced the dll and instead referenced the new decompiled project that I added to the solution.

When I went to debug my project, I expected to be able to step into the decompiled code. Instead, it stepped over the line of code where I expected the debugging to step into.

I discovered that if I changed my Debug options and unchecked the "Debug Just My Code" setting and then selected Debug => Windows => Modules and loaded the debug symbols for the decompiled project, I could step into the code of the decompiled project but I did not have normal debugging capabilities such as the ability to display variables values much less the ability to change code and continue.
I expected to be able to debug the decompiled project as normal. I could try to create a brand new project and copy each code file, one at a time into it to see if I could reconstruct a brand new project manually, but this would be long and tedious.

Any thoughts on what do I have to do to my decompiled project to be able to create a project that I can debug as a normal project?

Comment: When you build your decompiled project, did it have generated `pdb` file and the pdb file be copied into the main project output folder?  If so, please add its path under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`Symbols`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, it generated a pdb file but adding the debug\bin path to the list of symbols paths had no effect.

Comment: try to reset vs settings by `Tools`-->`Import and Export settings`-->`Reset all settings`. Then, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. Not sure whether it is your Decompiled project's problem. To troubleshoot it, creating a new vs project and migrate the old into it to test whether it works.